# Why this go code output like this?

Tags: multithreading, go

I'm learning Go langue in [here](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/5), and I modify a little code like this, I add a sleep(2s) before `quit <- 0`, and output index of fibonacci with `i`, below is my code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func fibonacci(c, quit chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for {
        select {
        case c <- x:
            x, y = y, x+y
        case <-quit:
            fmt.Println("quit")
            return
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    quit := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
            fmt.Println(i,<-c) // output index for result clearly
        }
        time.Sleep(2000*time.Millisecond) // add sleep for result clearly
        quit <- 0
    }()
    fibonacci(c, quit)
}
```

I find the stdout output 0-8 immediately, but wait 2 seconds it output 9th and then is "quit".

I move this code to a single go file and run it. At first it output 0-8 like above described, but after I change total number (from 10 to 9,8 or 3, whatever) some times, it output directly all fibonacci number immediately as I was excepted (of course it output `quit` after 2 seconds)!

I run the code in the browser (I used Chrome) it still output 9th delay, when I change 10 to 3, it output 0-2 immediately.

So I'm confused why does it output 9th delay?

UPDATE: I think I know why, because my output window too small to output whole result, but I always scroll down all time it still display 8th. If I scale output window larger, it will output 0-9 immediately. So is it a bug of this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug of this tutorial. If the output window (left-bottom) is too small, it will display without **the last line**, so the 9th won't be display immediately.

if I add `fmt.Println("foo")` after `fmt.Println(i,<-c)`, it won't output the last line contains `foo` string, but the 9th fibonacci will be displayed.

I capture the response in Chrome, it can tell how to display the result including what time it will output. So it must be a bug of page that swallow the last line. :D

PS: The response like this:

```
{
   "Errors":"",
   "Events":[
      {
         "Message":"0 0\nfoo\n1 1\nfoo\n2 1\nfoo\n3 2\nfoo\n4 3\nfoo\n5 5\nfoo\n6 8\nfoo\n7 13\nfoo\n8 21\nfoo\n9 34\nfoo\n",
         "Kind":"stdout",
         "Delay":0
      },
      {
         "Message":"quit\n",
         "Kind":"stdout",
         "Delay":2000000000
      }
   ]
}
```